# How to @mention myself in a chatter post using connect feed api and bring that in salesforce 1 notification bell?

Tags: chatter

I have used the below link to @mentioned myself in a chatter post, but the post is not registering in the "to me" section.  It is blue and shows up in the "What I Follow Tab, just not the "To Me" tab.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/09/salesforce1-notifications-from-apex.html

Comment: Your post does not contain a question.

Comment: How to use @mentioned myself in a chatter post using connect feed class

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are posting the feed item with an at-mention to yourself. In that case it will not show on the "To Me" feed. However if you post a comment to that feed item and at-mention yourself it would show.

The reason a post created by you will show in "What I Follow" is because you always "follow" yourself.

In the example you show that person is At Mentioning a user that is different than the posting user, which causes the Feed Item to appear in the the "To Me" feed.

For more detailed information about what feed posts show up where you can read:
[At mention people and groups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_add_mentioning_people.htm&language=en_US&type=0) and [Post Visibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_post_visibility.htm&language=en&type=0)

If you have more questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: even in the above blog they are posting in the feed item.I dont understand d difference between posting a comment to a feed item and posting the feed item??

Comment: In the blog the example they give is A User (we will call them Bob) posting a feed item and At-mention the user 'keir.chatter'. The difference here is Bob and 'keir.chatter' are not the same person. 

Chatter does filtering on the stream to prevent your own posts from showing up in your "To Me" feed (this is to prevent the To Me feed from being cluttered with your own posts). Unless you at-mention yourself in a comment. Then it will appear.

Comment: That is expected behavior.   If you post and mention yourself it will NOT show up in the To Me section.    In the example on the blog post, it is 2 different users, 1 doing the posting and another being at mentioned.

Comment: The class that I am using for posting is running in the system context and hence the person who is doing the posting should be system admin.However both the one who is posting and the one being mentioned are the same persons.

Comment: Chatter is a bit different than the other Triggers / Apex code. It runs as the context user:  "Chatter in Apex methods execute in the context of the context user, who is also referred to as the context user. The code has access to whatever the context user has access to. It doesn’t run in system mode like other Apex code."   from : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_overview.htm